# i was not declear in thiscscope cpp,but another i is working Q:ARRAY OF OBJECT

Tags: c++

` **SHOWING i IS NOT DECLEARED IN THIS SCOPE
question: of ARRAY OF OBJECT.**

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class employee{
char name[30];
float age;
public:
void getdata();
void putdata();

};
void employee::getdata()
{
    cout<<"Enter name"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter the age "<<endl;
    cin>>age;
}
void employee :: putdata()
{
    cout<<"Name "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"age "<<age<<endl;
}
const int size=3;
int main()
{
    employee manager[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<"manager details"<<i+1<<endl;
        manager[i].getdata();
    }
    cout<<endl;
    {
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            cout<<"manager details"<<i+1<<endl;
            manager[i].putdata();//main problem is here
    }
    return 0 ;
}`
```

here the link of error msg https://cpphelp4-u.blogspot.com/2021/10/array-of-object-error-msg-picture-link.html

Comment: you forgot curly braces for second `for()` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class employee{
char name[30];
float age;
public:
void getdata();
void putdata();

};
void employee::getdata()
{
    cout<<"Enter name"<<endl;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter the age "<<endl;
    cin>>age;
}
void employee :: putdata()
{
    cout<<"Name "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"age "<<age<<endl;
}
const int size=3;
int main()
{
    employee manager[size];//size?
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<"manager details"<<i+1<<endl;//i+1??
        manager[i].getdata();//i?
    }
    cout<<endl;

     for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        { //PROBLEM WAS HERE ,

        cout<<"manager details"<<i+1<<endl;
            manager[i].putdata();
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).